# Dealing with comma and fullstops as per convention

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I have various instance of strings such as:

```
- hello world,i am 2000to -> hello world, i am 2000 to
- the state was 56,869,12th -> the state was 66,869, 12th
- covering.2% -> covering. 2%
- fiji,295,000 -> fiji, 295,000
```

For dealing with first case, I came up with two step regex:

```
re.sub(r"(?<=[,])(?=[^\s])(?=[^0-9])", r" ", text) # hello world, i am 20,000to
re.sub(r"(?<=[0-9])(?=[.^[a-z])", r" ", text) # hello world, i am 20,000 to
```

But this breaks the text in some different ways and other cases are not covered as well. Can anyone suggest a more general regex that solves all cases properly. I've tried using `replace`, but it does some unintended replacements which in turn raise some other problems. I'm not an expert in regex, would appreciate pointers.

Comment: The example `covering.2%` seems ambiguous to me, because perhaps the decimal value is `.2%`

Comment: Every decimal value will start with some digit followed by `.`. So 0.2 instead of .2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach covers your cases above by breaking the text into tokens:

```
in_list = [
        'hello world,i am 2000to',
        'the state was 56,869,12th',
        'covering.2%',
        'fiji,295,000',
        'and another example with a decimal 12.3not4,5 is right out',
        'parrot,, is100.00% dead'
        'Holy grail runs for this portion of 100 minutes,!, 91%. Fascinating'
    ]
tokenizer = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z]+[\.,]?|(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})+|\d+)(?:\.\d+)?(?:%|st|nd|rd|th)?[\.,]?')
for s in in_list:
    print(' '.join(re.findall(pattern=tokenizer, string=s)))

#    hello world, i am 2000 to
#    the state was 56,869, 12th
#    covering. 2%
#    fiji, 295,000
#    and another example with a decimal 12.3 not 4, 5 is right out
#    parrot, is 100.00% dead
#    Holy grail runs for this portion of 100 minutes, 91%. Fascinating
```

Breaking up the regex, each token is the longest available substring with:

- Only letters with or without a period or comma,`[a-zA-Z]+[\.,]?`
- OR `|`
- A number-ish expression which could be

  - 1 to 3 digits `\d{1,3}` followed by any number of groups of comma + 3 digits `(?:,\d{3})+`
  - OR `|` any number of comma-free digits `\d+`
  - optionally a decimal place followed by at least one digit `(?:\.\d+)`,
  - optionally a suffix (percent, 'st', 'nd', 'rd', 'th') `(?:[\.,%]|st|nd|rd|th)?`
  - optionally period or comma `[\.]?`

Note the `(?:blah)` is used to suppress `re.findall`'s natural desire to tell you how every parenthesized group matches up on an individual basis. In this case we just want it to walk forward through the string, and the `?:` accomplishes this.

Comment: Thanks. But it creates a problem. It breaks instances such as 1.9% to 1. 9% (all such examples).

Comment: I expanded the regex to include this (new) case. Incidentally regex101.com is a great resource for testing out these things.

Comment: I found another test case which gets affected due to the regex. If decimal values are places at the end of string, for ex `world 12.9%.`, it removes the decimal giving `world 12.9%`. Can you please provide a general fix ? Thanks.

Comment: Sure - moving the period and comma `[/.,]?` to the end allows `%.` or cases like `12th,` to remain intact.